# Why is my method not being recognized by my generic object?

Tags: c#, .net, generic-list

I've made a code that has an interface and an abstract class to make my main function to work with both objects. As I started to work around my function everything was working perfectly until I needed to get a function from the object itself.
My function is:

```
void addNode<T>(List<T> genericList) where T : IGraphs{
                T genericNode = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                genericNode.Number = contDirected;
                
                if (genericList.Count > 0)
                {
                    string connectedNode = "";
                    while (!connectedNode.Equals("0") && genericList.RemainingNodesExist(undirectedGraphs, genericNode))
                    {
                  }      
                }
            }
        }
```

Obviously the function is not yet finished but the problem is on my last "while". As I try to get the method "RemainingNodesExist", the IDE gives me an advice saying that List does not have a definition for the method. Im not sure why is that since I have it on my classes:

```
    public interface IGraphs
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public List<int> LinkedNumbers { get; set; }

}

public abstract class AbstractGraphs<T>
{
    public abstract bool RemainingNodesExist(List<T> list, T node);
}
```

And on the classes that inherit from those above:

```
public class DirectedGraph: AbstractGraphs<DirectedGraph>, IGraphs
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<int> LinkedNumbers { get; set; }

    public DirectedGraph()
    {
        Number = Number;
        LinkedNumbers = new List<int>();
    }

    public override bool RemainingNodesExist(List<DirectedGraph> list, DirectedGraph node)
    {
        int numbersConnected = node.LinkedNumbers.Count;
        if (numbersConnected != list.Count)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

- 

```
    public UndirectedGraph()
    {
        Number = Number;
        LinkedNumbers = new List<int>();
    }

    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<int> LinkedNumbers { get; set; }

    public override bool RemainingNodesExist(List<UndirectedGraph> list, UndirectedGraph node)
    {
        int numbersConnected = node.LinkedNumbers.Count;
        if (numbersConnected != list.Count)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To better summarize whats my goal...
I have 2 objects that are exactly the same in properties, but the methods will probably be different in some situations. I used the generic class T because the program will use a list of objects not yet defined that can be any of the two objects mentioned above. What I want my program to do is run the "addNode" function and run the method of both objects based on their type.

Has anyone had to deal with a similar problem or could give me some direction on how to solve this?

Comment: Quite unclear why do you expect `List<T> genericList` somehow to become `AbstractGraphs<T>`. Some [edit] of the question is needed. Also re-read [mre] guidance on posting code - you probably should be able to simplify code in the question but keep the core of the issue there (i.e. most of addNode can be removed I think).

Comment: this looks very peculiar, `class x: genericBase<X>`, are you sure you need to be both a class hierachy and generic (and I see an interface too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very suspicious of this code base, it looks way way too complicated.

But to answer your specific question

```
         while (!connectedNode.Equals("0") && genericList.RemainingNodesExist(undirectedGraphs, genericNode))
```

attempts to call a method on `genericList`, thats a `List<XXX>` passed as a parameter

That method (RemainingNodesExist) is defined here

```
public abstract class AbstractGraphs<T>
{
    public abstract bool RemainingNodesExist(List<T> list, T node);

}
```

Its a method of a class called `AbstractGraphs<T>`

Which has no relation to `List<AnythinG>`

Its hard to say what you need to change because this is such a convoluted set of classes.

Maybe if you can explain why you think that method would be callable on a list that might make it clearer

Comment: In fact the list did not have any relation with the method, the objects inside the list do. Sorry for not seeing that before posting it and thanks for the heads up about the complexity, I might change the structure.

Comment: @MatheusReimer seeing `public class DirectedGraph: AbstractGraphs<DirectedGraph>, IGraphs` immediately sets of alarms for me. I suspect all you need is a class hierarchy